# Django generate custom ID

Tags: python, django, django-models

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698729/django-how-to-add-a-custom-id-column-to-identify-my-objects) but there is no specific answer yet. I want to create custom `id` that starts with letter. When a new record comes into database I want to change the `id` to A00001, .... A00002, .... A00010, ...A10000 etc. The `id` will be always in range `99999- 00001` so how can I do that?

**my model is simple:**

```
class Custom(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: What would you use this for? If you want to make an `id` with auto increment integer, you need a DBMS such as MySQL or a number counter using In-Memory DB like Redis.

Comment: For production app. They wanted this `id` format

Comment: @Telmunn How about using id as just Integer and make an another field or property which add 'A00~' format string to id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **`AutoField`** field is a kind of **`IntegerField`** field, so you can't use PKs as `A00001` .

So, the possible way to achieve the requirement is to change the **`AutoField`** to **`CharField`**.
**Technically you can use *"String PK Field"* But, you should be aware of the problems/performance issues if you are going to use that.**
Here I found one nice SO post that explains the same - [Strings as Primary Keys in SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-sql-database)
========================================================================

If you still really wish to migrate to *String PKs*, read the following
First you need to use the **`CharField`** instead of **`AutoField`** and override the **`save()`** method of model

```
from django.db.models import Max


class Custom(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            max = Custom.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('id'))['id_max']
            self.id = "{}{:05d}".format('A', max if max is not None else 1)
        super().save(*kwargs)
```

Comment: @BearBrown sorry, I dont get you. Can you edit directly?

Comment: This code would be hard to use in production. If multiple users try it simultaneously, IntegrityError would be raised.

Comment: @JPG you did a disservice, it can give many trouble with perfomance IMHO

Comment: @BearBrown Yeah. btw, I updated the answer with little bit more information

Comment: @JPG I am getting ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str' for the line self.id = "{}{:05d}".format('A', max if max is not None else 1)
My ID if it is string then it should throw that error right? How will it work?

Comment: @SukanyaPai The value of **`max`** expects in ***`int`*** type and in your case, it is **`str`**.

Comment: I had to modify this Line of assigning to self.id as below:
self.id = "{}{:05d}".format('A', int(max[1:]) if max is not None else 1)

Observer the slicing done and conversion to int in max variable.

Now to solve the problem of getting the correct id_max, I followed the this: 

custom=Custom.objects.last()  (new line)
max=custom.id if custom is not None else None

Comment: Hi @JPG, still getting Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str' for the line

Answer (score 5):

string as Primary Key not good idea if you plan to do references to the table, so i recommend you to add a property, for example:

```
class Custom(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    @property
    def sid(self):
        return "A%05d" % self.id
```

and to do queries you can do processing the input values, for example:

```
s_input = "A%05d" % 231 # 'A00231'
number = s_input[1:] # '00231'
input_id = int(number) # 231
```

Comment: I think Indent should be modified.

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: @BearBrown I tried your approach in my Django Model, but still my id field gets default 1,2,3 values while creating. Can you please help? I did the same thing, applied migrations and then started server and created data.

Comment: @SukanyaPai in this solution the PK in the database is still integer and only property `sid` is string

Comment: @Bear Brown does it mean the sid property is the new ID that I should track?  I checked my database, there was no sid in my table. I have performed makemigrations and migrate operations as well.  Can you tell me where I went wrong please?

Comment: sid is property of the model and it doesn't exists in the database

Comment: @Bear Brown ok, so to clarify again the ID will be stored in the customised ID format right? Because for me it is storing as integers itself (1, 2, ...). I have applied migrations as well. Can you please help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I also have another way, That i use in my django project. Here are some code

```
def ids():
no = Employee.objects.count()
if no == None:
    return 1
else:
    return no + 1
emp_id = models.IntegerField(('Code'), default=ids, unique=True, editable=False)


id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=30)
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.id = "{}{:08d}".format('ABC', self.emp_id)
    super().save(*kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create a new field for the custom id in the models and the process in the backend. You can set that as `primary_key` with `unique=True` and `editable=False`:

```
class Custom(models.Model):
  id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=10)
  uid= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.set_uid()                                 # calling the set_uid function

  def set_uid(self):
    if not self.uid:                               # if uid of the instance is blank
      uid = "CUS" + str(self.id + (10 ** 5))       # generating the uid
      customer= Custom.objects.get(id=self.id)     # getting the instance
      customer.uid = uid                           # allocating the value
      customer.save()                              # saving the instance

  def __str__(self):
    return self.uid
```

Can also merge the `set_uid()` inside the `save()` where the function is called:

```
class Custom(models.Model):
  id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=10)
  uid= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.uid:                                # if uid of the instance is blank
      self.uid = "CUS" + str(self.id + (10 ** 5))   # generating the uid and allocating the value
      self.save()                                   # saving the instance
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use answer of @JPG, but it has a bug.
The bug is becasue it can't auto increment.
I fixed the bug, and this my resultant code:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        max = YourModel.objects.aggregate(
            id_max=models.Max('id'))['id_max']
        if max is not None:
            max += 1
        else:
            max = 100
        self.id = "{:08d}".format(
            max)  # id from 100 to start
    super().save(*kwargs)
```