# How to add integers to primary key field in Django Model at save

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key

In my Django app, I have created a model with the id (primary key) as a `CharField` of length 6. I am using a custom validator which allows the user to only enter integers only. Is there a way to add zeros before the input if it is less than the "six" character length specified in the field definition.

For example, the user enters value **1234** in the primary key field. Now I want that at save the pk field value should be saved as **001234**.

I tried doing that at `save` but two records are getting created, one with the input by the user and the other with the zero(s) added.

Is this at all possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

### Edit

Here is what I am doing (seems quite *low-tech* to me though):

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    plant_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,..,)
    plant_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Plant/W.Area")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if len(self.plant_id) == 4:
            ramp_up_obj_id = '00' + str(self.plant_id)
            self.plant_id = str(ramp_up_obj_id)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The result on save is (as narrated above): For entered value of **1001**, there two records created. One with **1001** and the other one as **001001**.

Comment: Could you include your code in your question? It might be that you're close to what you need to do - it sounds like it should be possible - but there may be a bug in your code that people can help you fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) function before calling `super().save` method and call `super().save()` only once.

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    plant_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,..,)
    plant_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Plant/W.Area")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.plant_id = str(self.plant_id).zfill(6)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this answer here: [Django generate custom ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070462/django-generate-custom-id)

With `@property` (I highly suggest you to go with this instead)

```py
@property
def sid(self):
    return "%05d" % self.id
```

With `CharField`

```py
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=10)

def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        max = Rate.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('id'))['id_max'] + 1
        self.id= "{:05d}".format(max if max is not None else 1)
    super().save(*kwargs)
```