# Generating unique id in a model with prefix of field value of another model

Tags: django

I created two models "Category" and "Item". There is a field "title" in category model, I want the value of the "title field" to be prefix of my "unique id field" in Item module can anyone suggest me a solution for this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `id` in django models is something like this:

```py
class Custom(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

So, the possible way to achieve the requirement is to change the `IntegerField` to `CharField`.

**Technically you can use "String PK Field" But, you should be aware of the problems/performance issues if you are going to use that.** more: [Strings as Primary Keys in SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-sql-database)

If you still really wish to migrate to String PKs:

First you need to use the `CharField` instead of `IntegerField` and override the `save()` method of model

```py
from django.db.models import Max


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            max = Item.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('id'))['id_max']
            self.id = "{}{:05d}".format(self.prefix, max if max is not None else 1)
        super().save(*kwargs)
```

According to this: [Django generate custom ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070462/django-generate-custom-id)

Comment: Thank you for the solution 
 I will let you know if it works, Thank you

Comment: the 'id' you mentioned in "if statement" is from "Item model" right

Comment: yes it is. and you can set `max_length=10` or `max_length=100` in the field declaration. because I do not know your category `title` max length I dont set max_length for Item `id`

Comment: you should set `max_length` of `id` and `prefix` based on your requirement

Comment: Ok thank you, I set my id and prefix, Can we add value which is stored in title as prefix here.

Comment: @I.SRIRAM Yes we can. We may have many approches for this requirement. you can define custom model field for this requirement. read this: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/)

Comment: My Category Model
``class Category(models.Model):
    cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)``

And in my Item Model

``product_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
    prefix = models.OneToOneField(Category, to_field='title', related_name='prefix', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.product_id:
            max = Item.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('product_id'))['id_max']
            self.product_id = "{}{:10}".format(self.prefix, max if max is not None else 1)
        super().save(*kwargs)``

Comment: As per the above code. I used cat_title from category model as prefix to the unique id which i used in Item model, I can generate unique id with prefix as cat title only once because it is requesting to create cat_title  field to be unique,So if i add unique=True in Category model, I can only save a single item with unique prefix can you help me with it.
Thank You.